# Summarising data using tidyr/dplyr functions

Tags: r

Below is my Data frame:

```
  Species   Type  Contents (kg)
1       T      f           0.0710000
2       T      f           0.1100000
3       W      f           0.0200000
4       W      f           0.0200000
5       S      f           0.2100000
6       S      f           0.2800000
7       T      w           1.1400000
8       T      w           0.6000000
9       W      w           0.5600000
10      W      w           0.5600000
11      S      w           1.9800000
12      S      w           3.1200000
```

Using dplyr functions I've got the mean and variance of my `type f` but I would also like to split the results by the `species` as well and was wondering how I could do this using tidyr/dplyr functions.

This is what I've used to find the mean and variance of my `type f` above.

```
summarise(group_by(Item,Type[2]),Mean = mean(Item$Contents (kg)),Variance = var(Item$Contents (kg)))
```

Comment: `df %>% group_by(Species,Type[1]) %>% summarise(m1=mean(Contents),var1=var(Contents))`

Comment: You should probably spend time reading a `dplyr` tutorial because this code seems a bit off. Should be something more like `Item %>% group_by(Type, Species) %>% summarize(mean=mean(Contents))` YOu shouldn't be using `$` in basic dplyr statements and i'm not sure what your intentions were with the `[2]` but that seems a bit off as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relatively simple with `dplyr` just call `mutate`

```
df <- read.table(text =
               " Row   Species   Type  Contents(kg)
                  1       T      f           0.0710000
                  2       T      f           0.1100000
                  3       W      f           0.0200000
                  4       W      f           0.0200000
                  5       S      f           0.2100000
                  6       S      f           0.2800000
                  7       T      w           1.1400000
                  8       T      w           0.6000000
                  9       W      w           0.5600000
                  10      W      w           0.5600000
                  11      S      w           1.9800000
                  12      S      w           3.1200000",
             header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


library(dplyr)


df %>%
  group_by(Type, Species) %>%
  mutate(meanByTypeandSpecies = mean(Contents.kg.))
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to make this more specific and isolate just the Type f Items?

Comment: yeah something like this you mean: `df %>% filter(Type == "f") %>% group_by( Species) %>% mutate(meanByTypeandSpecies = mean(Contents.kg.))`

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use the pipe utility and summarise to get your summary statistics by group :

```
Item %>%
    group_by(Species, Type) %>%
    summarise(
              mean = mean(Contents.kg.),
              variance = var(Contents.kg.)
    )
```

Comment: This provides the same mean for each combination of species and type.